# Extract year from day/month in postgresql and check if date is or is not the first and/or last of the year

Tags: postgresql, function, date

A java application reads a CSV file, this file have 2 columns:

```
X     Y
22/11 5
23/11 8
24/11 6
```

X and Y are X-axis and Y-axis, respectively, where X is supposed to be a date. It misses the year.

I must insert these values in a table, for doing that I'm preparing a function():

```
BEGIN
 UPDATE my_table set timestamp=to_timestamp(in_x_data), price=in_y_data WHERE timestamp = to_timestamp(in_x_data);
 IF FOUND THEN 
  RETURN;
 END IF;
 BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO my_table ( timestamp, price ) VALUES ( to_timestamp(in_x_data), in_y_data );
 END;
RETURN;
END;
```

Since X is not a timestamp, I must find a way to "convert" it to a real date:

1) I know that the java application runs once everyday;

2) If those above are the values it means that the application ran on the 23/11 - The application (or this file) have always the day of yesterday and the day of tomorrow, sometimes even the day after tomorrow.

**What I'd like to achieve**:

The idea is to develop the function so that it reads the year (maybe from `select date_part('year', now());` ) and use this value (2018) to create a real date:

```
22/11/2018
23/11/2018
24/11/2018
```

Keeping in mind of the 1st and last of the year, so I guess an IF-ELSE should be inserted.

Something like:

```
// today is 30/12/2018
year = select date_part('year', now());

new_x_data = to_timestamp(in_x_data + '/' +year);
// new_x_data == 01/01/2018
IF (new_x_data was long time ago ) { 
  new_x_data = to_timestamp(in_x_data + '/' +year+1);
  // new_x_data == 01/01/2019
}
```

Excuse me for killing decades of programming.

Well, the same should be applicable to future and past days around the start and end of the year.

I have no clue on how to do it and I'm also not much familiar with PLpgSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be useful for some people searching what I was searching that day:

```
DECLARE
-- accept dd/mm and add current year /yyyy
in_date timestamp;

BEGIN
 SELECT to_date(in_x_data||to_char(current_date,'/yyyy'),'dd/mm/yyyy') INTO in_date;

-- check if month of in_date is January and current date is December, if true, add 1 year to in_date
 IF ( (SELECT date_part('month', in_date) = 1) AND (SELECT date_part('month', now()) = 12) ) THEN
   in_date := in_date + interval '1 year';

-- if in_date is December but current date is January, remove 1 year
 ELSIF   ( (SELECT date_part('month', in_date) = 12) AND (SELECT date_part('month', now()) = 1) ) THEN
   in_date := in_date - interval '1 year';
 END IF;

 UPDATE my_table SET timestamp=in_date, price=in_y_data WHERE timestamp = in_date;
 IF FOUND THEN 
  RETURN;
 END IF;
 BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO my_table ( timestamp, price ) VALUES ( in_date, in_y_data );  
 END;
RETURN;
END;
```

Thanks to `@a_horse_with_no_name` for his answer, that helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two solutions: build a date from the string `22/11` and extract day and month from it, then use that as an input to `make_date()`

```
select make_date(extract(year from current_date)::int, 
                 extract(month from to_date('22/11', 'dd/mm'))::int, 
                 extract(day from to_date('22/11', 'dd/mm'))::int)
```

`to_date('22/11', 'dd/mm')` returns a date with the year 0001, so another option would be to add the required number of years to that.

```
select (to_date('22/11', 'dd/mm') + interval '1' year * extract(year from current_date)::int)::date
```

Adding an `interval` to a `date` returns a `timestamp`, that's why the final result needs to be cast to a date using `::date`

---

An alternative to `make_date()` is `to_date()`:

```
select to_date('22/11'||to_char(current_date,'/yyyy'),'dd/mm/yyyy');
```

Comment: It's a good logic behind but this is probably my mistake: I have postgresql 9.3 and make_date does not exist in this version. Rather I upgrade or find alternatives but it's a production environment and I can't simply upgrade it, I'll see what I can do.
Back to the answer, I don't see where it adds 1 year + 1 when it's the 31st december today and it inserts in the table values for the 1st and 2nd of january. What I read is that it will always add to the day and month the current year. Am I wrong? Thanks of course for your answer, I'd not have thought of this

Comment: @Nihvel: there is actually a more compact version using to_date(). See my edit

Comment: Yes the to_date() is a good and quick alternative, thanks! Still there's the date issue but I'm thinking how to fix this: the function can extract the latest value inserted and here check if the new value is (in month) bigger than the previous. If so, increase the year. For past dates I should use the same logic but removing 1 year and here there will be a Update since the value is there in the table already but Y (price column) might contain updated value.
I'll get back here when things get complicated before accepting the answer ;)